# Architectural flow diagram ? MVC4 with EF & mds services

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, master-data-services

We gonna deal with a application which can be consumed from various devices .

I what the flow diagram from which layer to which layer like that ..

I tried one if i am wrong correct me and any clarity comment i will try to be elobarative

VIEW <---> Controller <---> Model (Domain objects ) <----> BLL <----> WEB-API <---> DAL (EF 6.0 ) <----> MDS(Services on master data)

I am not sure i am right or wrong any corrections are appreciated . I am feeling confused where to keep BLL ? ? can i consume mds in entity framework which is inside DAL else need to create separate layer ? i am confused

Share your thought's :) Ty

Comment: I would put very strict controls on the MDS layer. Unless you're building an MDS utility or Front End, do not expose MDS data to anything of your own design other than the ETL that copies the MDS data into the data source for the DAL.

Comment: yes that's an useful insight .Any ideas regarding BLL , model , web-Api communication . Yesterday there been this tought i am not sure how sucessful will this be i.e WEBAPI project ---> service layer(wcf services to consume Business logic) ---> BLL --> repository(some sort of communication interface) ---> DLL --> MDS .
Uff these days banging my head too much confused

Comment: if webapi be upfront , if so .. how to deal with end user thing ? as it wont generate view ? –  user2061595 just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Web-API component is in the wrong place - it's a UI element generating/processing UI requests? Should it not be in the same group at the view?

The Model and the BLL would have a close relationship. If all devices were accessing the MVC front end you could possibly opt for a traditional MVC model? In older/simpler MVC projects the models were sometimes just EF objects - but abstraction is recommended. Typically Model classes would be composed of EF objects, and the BLL would be functions included in the model class.